# Multiple versions of software at Azure marketplace and upgrade policy

Tags: azure, upgrade, azure-marketplace

We are planning to put our product on Azure marketplace. The product is installed on Windows server machines and is distributed in nature. The architecture that suits us the most is Iaas, however, we are concerned about keeping multiple versions and the upgrade policy. We normally release 2 versions of the software every year plus there could be more patches and service packs.

Please also note that our software doesn't have in-place upgrades. That means to upgrade our software, it is needed to be uninstalled and reinstalled.

We've googled to get some help but couldn't find any satisfactory answers. I'll appreciate if someone could. The questions we are really concerned about are;

1. How many versions can/should we keep on marketplace?
2. What should be the process to upgrade software on machines already running on Azure?
3. How to handle public patches and service packs?

Thanks.